# Issue with export node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a variable from one js file to another in a node.js environment. Here are the files with only the important bits -

file1.js

```
var socket = io.connect();
export default socket;
```

file2.js

```
import socket from "./chat.js";
```

My file1.js showed an error,that Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' . I searched the net and the reason was I am trying to use ES6 import/export syntax in node js environment. So I ran my server.js file using the esm package.

node -r esm app.js

app.js file -

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html')
})

app.use(express.static(__dirname))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

This does not work either,returns the same error of **unexpected token export**. Can anyone help me out please?

Note:- My app.js file is a simple express file which has a get request to a HTML page using the file1.js.

Comment: You need to use `module.exports = {socket}` instead of `export default` if you're using node syntax.

Comment: You need babel package to transpile your code. Then Import export will work.

Comment: @DorianB, I tried using module.exports but it throws an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined."

Comment: @QubaishBhatti Tried to use bable but then came across this article https://timonweb.com/tutorials/how-to-enable-ecmascript-6-imports-in-nodejs/

Comment: Oh Man!! Go with @DorianB, and do `var socket = require('path_of_file')`

Comment: @mehta-rohan,throws an error Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.

Comment: Share the code...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use ESM modules syntax, this code will works :

file1.js :

```js
const socket = { test: 1 }
module.exports = socket
```

file2.js :

```js
const socket = require('./file1')
console.log(socket)
```

Running `node file2.js` will log `{ test: 1 }`.
It uses node module syntax not ESM one but it works.

Comment: Tried your code in using two javascript files and it works. But put the file2.js in a HTML page and it won't work. This gives a Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined error. I assume this is because,require is not client-sided and only works in the server side code which is my app.js.

Comment: Yes `require` is exclusive to Node and does not work in browser. To use import client-side, you will have to use webpack or another module bundler.

Comment: Okay. I never had to struggle this much with such a minute functionality as import/export. All other languages I have worked with have it so easy.

Comment: JavaScript modules are very complicated and many solutions (as modules bundlers) exist to patch this missing functionality in the language.

Answer (score -4):

Use can use `alanode` binary from the [ÀLaMode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/alamode) transpiler (0 dependencies unlike Babel's ~250), which performs a regex-based from imports to modules in Node.

```
npm i alanode --save-dev
yarn add alanode
```

Then add in package.json a script:

```
{
  "name": "your-package",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "...etc",
    "alanode": "alanode"
  }
}
```

After that you can run your scripts with it:

```
$> npm run alanode -- app
```

Or if using yarn just the following, and you don't need to add a script in package.json:

```
$> yarn alanode app
```

If you want to run standard node without the `alanode` proxy, you'll need to create a file that requires `alamode`, e.g., `src/index.js`:

```
require('alamode')()
require('./app')
```

It's called a *require hook*: every JS file will be run against the transpilation function first to update those imports to `require` statements and exports to `module.export` assignments. This way, the imports will be transpiled automatically even when you run with plain Node. Then you can build your source code as well:

```
$> yarn alamode src -o build -s
```

Where `-o` is the build folder and `-s` means no source maps which you don't need as the output is very much like the original, except that imports/exports are changed.

The difference between `yarn` and `npm` is that when there's a binary installation of a local dependency (it has `bin` in `package.json`), `yarn` can be used to just run `yarn <name-of-bin>` to get it to spawn, but `npm` can't so you need to create a script for it, and even then add `--` so that arguments are passed through.

Just a note of caution, if you have template strings that use a protocol with `//`, ÀLaMode might break, e.g.,

```
const URL = `ws://localhost`
export default socket

const something else = `test`
```

so you need to lightly tweak the code like

```
const URL = `ws:/` + `/localhost
```

as 2 consecutive slashes trigger a comment replacement to prevent false positives. It's slightly inconvenient.

Comment: please always disclose affiliation when promoting your own product